# Make Atom behave like WebStorm on auto-indentation

Tags: webstorm, atom-editor, auto-indent

This question is a bit hard to explain in pure text so I've made two gifs.

I would like Atom to behave like this when writing code. Imagine you have a block of code and realize you need to wrap it in a function, if-statement or some other sort of `{}`-ish thing.

When writing in WebStorm it automatically indents the correct way IMO, so I would like to achieve this same behaviour in Atom.

So this is **WebStorm** (the way I like)
[image: WebStorm style auto indentation]

And this is the **Atom version** (the way I dislike)
[image: Atom style auto indentation]

Comment: Is seems to be something wrong with the links. This is WebStorm the way i like:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4070459/webstorm-indent.gif

And this is Atom (the way i dislike):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4070459/atom-indent.gif

To be clear: I want Atom to behave like WebStorm